# Device is not showing in mfpconsole after registering for push notification via rest API

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-console

Am using MFP confidential clients to register my device for push notification.

but after getting 201 (created response) from the server , my device is not showing in device section of mfp console.

MFP version: 8.0

This is the response i got after registering via REST API.

```
{
    "createdTime": "2018-07-17T07:04:18Z",
    "lastUpdatedTime": "2018-07-17T07:04:18Z",
    "createdMode": "API",
    "deviceId": "asadasdadadd",
    "userId": "anonymous",
    "token": "token",
    "platform": "A",
    "phoneNumber": "12345678",
    "href": "http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:9080/imfpush/v1/apps/abc.abc.abc/devices/12345-678"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have registered your device against the Push service endpoint. This is different from the Devices registration from MobileFirst SDK that shows up in the Devices console.

MobileFirst console lists devices only registered using Apps built with MobileFirst SDKs.

If you are only registering your device for Push, it does not appear in the console. If you want your device appearing in the Devices console, do Push device registration within a mobile app and not using confidential client.

Comment: That means , if we are using confidential client and rest api for push registration , we will not able to see any logs in the mfpconsole and to send notification also we need to use rest api ?

Comment: @ArjunTRaj, when you use Push notifications via SDK or REST endpoints, server logs ( traces) will record it. To send notification , REST API is the only way.